# Obtaining Geocoding results with county value from ArcGIS world geocoder

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online

The ArcGIS World Geocoder returns pretty good results for our use, with two exceptions that are deal breakers and I can't yet find answers.

1. There don't appear to be county values consistently returned for certain types of searches.  Notice this search for a postal code:

http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=80205&f=pjson&outFields=*

The "Subregion" is where I would expect to see "county" listed.  Similarly, I have not once yet seen "Nbrhd" populated, though that would be very useful.  Without the county value though, ArcGIS isn't a solution for us.

2. Is there a way to get the State/Province/Region *code* instead of the full name?  Same question goes for Country.

Comment: Since a zip code can cross county boundaries, I wouldn't expect a return value for that parameter at the zip level. Have you tried it with a specific street address, or even just a city? Your example is also potentially problematic, because that may be both city and county of Denver, and maybe it's only returning the one and not the other. Boulder would be another example of that. Not sure about returning the code vs name. Have you tried contacting Esri directly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris.  We were receiving county data with Google's geocoding searches for zip code.  80205 is squarely containted within Denver County, though I do understand your point regarding the postal code <-> county matching issue.

This search for a City, State **does** return a county
[link](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=Lebanon,%20MO&f=pjson&outFields=*)  

Also, I had not contacted Esri directly because we're evaluating this as a potential solution but it seems they only offer paid support.

Comment: Interesting to note that this address match does not include either county or neighborhood name:

[link](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=2034%20Vine%20St.%20Denver,%20CO%2080205&f=pjson&outFields=*)

Comment: Also found this unanswered similar question:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107759

Comment: I'd imagine if you contact sales and describe the situation/issue, they can help get you an answer. While it's true support normally costs, I'm sure there is some method in place if they want to make sales. Looking at your three examples, I notice all are being handled differently (POI, Point Address, Postal Address), which would suggest different locators. Perhaps some of them are county/subregion aware and some aren't. Would have to dig deeper into 'how it works' docs, or possibly if there are specific submit formats. Don't know about neighborhoods, as that info is usually highly localized.